# In Subversion, why is there a copy of trunk in my tagged revision?

Tags: svn

My project is set up in Subversion with the standard *trunk / branches / tags* structure. I created a tag with a `copy` command like so:

```
svn copy /path/to/project/trunk /path/to/project/tags/cya_tag
```

This creates a copy just as I expected, but I can also see a new directory `/project/tags/cya_tag/trunk` that contains *another* copy of the trunk.

My guess is that this copy is used to track where the tagged version branched off of the trunk, but I can't find any documentation anywhere that states this. Am I right?

Comment: SVN is not branch aware.  It views this simply as a copy so it would not maintain a copy for tracking where something branches.

Comment: My guess would be that you (or somebody else in your project team) accidentally ran the same command after the first time, thus copying trunk as a subdirectory into `cya_tag`.  `svn log` will be enlightening.

Comment: To follow up on ZoogieZork's comment, if you want to reuse the tag `cya_tag`, you'll have to delete the existing one before doing `svn copy`. As Pace said, tagging is just copying in Subversion. If the copy destination already exists, the source gets copied into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For svn /branches or /trunk is a common directories as any other. It doesn't process them in any special way. Somebody maybe has executed to get what you see:

```
svn copy /path/to/project/ /path/to/project/tags/cya_tag
```

To understand this check svn log:

```
svn log /path/to/project/tags/cya_tag
```